# how to configure wildfly jdbc to azure sql without password

Tags: azure-sql-database, wildfly

Has anyone been able to configure wildfly (v20) to connect to an azure SQL as a datasource without saving the passwords in the clear?

When using other sql versions, we use NTLM / integrated security=true. Works great when we run wildfly from windows services with the system account. But Azure SQL does not support integrated security, we get the dreaded message, does not support windows login.

I've been searching for a while and found the credential store option. But the secret to the credential store needs to be in the clear in the standalone.xml file. That helps but technically it can still be used. I saw also you can use a 3rd party script to fetch the pwd but we don't have anything like that.

It looks like in theory you could use an azure managed identity, but not sure how to setup standalone.xml to use that. Anyone ever succeeded with azure sql?

Thank you!